# Ubuntu not showing in boot manager of OS after dual booting with Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I am using a HP laptop which has both SSD and HDD. Windows 10 is installed in the SSD so I have decided to install Linux in HDD. I have allocated around 50GB for Ubuntu 20.04 and installed it in the HDD, but after restarting the computer GRUB is not showing I thought it may be problem with the ordering of the OS in the boot loader so I decided to check in the BIOS, to my surprise even after successful installation of the OS, OS boot manager in BIOS is showing only windows and there is no trace of Linux. I am unable to understand what is the problem I have tried with different combinations of the secure boot and legacy support but nothing seems to work for me.

Snapshot of BIOS:
[image: bios]

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is installed with UEFI, you better turn off legacy boot, and boot in Ubuntu installation media and make sure it is installed as UEFI as well. Because if it is installed in Legacy mode, the it's harder to handover boot to GRUB. If its UEFI, you can just point to it from BIOS, like in screenshot. By the way, using UEFI requires a FAT partition at /boot/efi and some other quirks. Check this [Arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#UEFI_systems). Don't know if Ubuntu installer do that out of the box. THis may also be helpful [Manajro wiki: Dual Boot Guide](https://archived.forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-dual-boot-manjaro-windows-10-step-by-step/52668). See how to set up EFI.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an HP bug, this solution worked for me:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=368217

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).